# Is it direct speech?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

I have a question regarding the sentence below.

> If you say “I hate grammar,” you mean “I have a lot of difficulties
>   with understanding rules how to use words correctly.”

Is it direct speech after the word *say*? Is it direct speech after the word *mean*? (*You* here is used as *one* — "if one says.") Should I use a comma after *say* and/or *mean*? What about quotation marks?

edit: Additional question. What about the word *think*? An example: He thought, "Where should I go?" Is it direct speech?

Comment: I think that there is an implied 'to say' after 'mean'. If you say, "X" , you mean to say, "Y".

Comment: With quotes, *you* and *I* are the same person. Without quotes, *you* would be reporting how someone else feels about grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the quotation marks. If someone actually said (or wrote, or something like that) you should use the quotation marks. So if someone said "I hate grammar" quotation marks are obligatory. The second sentence, however, is not (I assume) something someone actually said, but it is an indirect quotation, and therefore it should not have the quotation marks.

For the rule about the comma see for example http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/quotes/marks. He says it is a matter of personal preference, so a comma after say is your own choice, just be consistent. A comma after mean would be wrong.
There are also sources (such as this one http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/punctuation-in-direct-speech) that say that the comma is obligatory after say and not a matter of preference.

A thought can either be written between quotation marks or written in italics (see for example http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/quotation-marks/internal-dialogue-italics-or-quotes/). Some people think that using quotation marks for thought is wrong (http://www.dailywritingtips.com/dealing-with-a-characters-internal-thoughts/) and only writing thoughts in italics is acceptable (or no punctuation at all).